# Xcode Dock Icon Shadow Effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'm attempting to replicate the drop shadow effect used by Xcode for it's dock icon. Specifically, the shadow around the blue square. It seems to be some mixture of outer-glow, drop-shadow and stroke, but I can't get it to look quite right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the standard and zoomed-in views:

[image: Xcode Standard Logo]

[image: Xcode Zoomed Logo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?
[image]

If you're going for "pixel perfect" then contact the person who made the set -- other than that I can simply suggest to keep playing around with it.

Comment: +1/Accepted - Thanks! That got me a lot closer, and I figured it out. Wound up doing DS: 0, 0, 5; Stroke: 1px 50%.

Comment: Good luck trying to contact the *Apple* designer :P

Comment: Haha, yeah. ^^ I just meant that basically a "pixel perfect" match isn't going to happen.